# Why is my ping so high when playing a game running on a VM via VMWare Workstation 17? What can I do to lower the ping?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

This is a screenshot of the virtual machine networking settings :

First the option was on the NAT: used to share the host's IP address but then I tried to change it to the bridged connected directly, but it didn't solve the problem either.

The whole windows 8.1 and also in the game in the main menu it's working fast and fine only when connecting a server it get slow because the high ping.

Networking settings:

[image: networking settings]

The ping in the game runs between 180 and 240 and sometimes more.

I don't have a problem is with the networking in my Windows 10 when playing not on the virtual machine.

In the virtual machine I have Windows 8.1 and the game I'm trying to play is *Battlefield: Bad Company 2*.

But when I'm running the virtual machine and then running game if I'm back to the Windows 10 it looks likes everything is slow in the Windows 10. Only when closing the virtual machine after a few seconds the Windows 10 gets back to it's regular speed working.

Comment: The VM is using the Windows 10 network adapter, so if it's using a lot of bandwidth, than app on Windows 10 will have less bandwidth left and will need to share in it.

Comment: Are you sure the game is slow because the ping is high… or the ping is high because the VM is running slowly? How much RAM does the host have? I see you've assigned 16 to the VM so I hope you have 32 or more.

Comment: @Tetsujin i have 32gb so i gave 16 to the vm and 4 cpu's to the vm. maybe because i set 4 cup's ? because i can't change it to 1 now it's grayed out.  also the video card i think it's setting to get from the physic video card.  but maybe the problem is the cpu's ?

Comment: @Tetsujin i see in the game the ping is too high.  and in the game main menu everything is working smooth not slow at all.  when entering the game and connecting to a server then it's getting very slow like when loading stuff it's loading it in parts like hanging and stuttering a bit then when loading the server it's almost not moving because the ping is too high.  i can take a screenshot from the game while playing to show the ping but i'm sure it's the ping that make it slow while playing.

Comment: You can usually only change that data when the VM is shut down, not paused or sleeping/hibernated. GPU is often just emulated, not real [depends on the specifics of the VM & I'm not familiar with VMWare to know for certain]

Comment: @Tetsujin maybe i need some how to give more bandwidth to the vm from the newtorking ? maybe just tell it to use the physic network adapter is not enough ?

Comment: VMs are inherently slow. Gaming on VMs needs a wickedly fast machine with a lot of cores & a lot of clock speed. If they make the host use swap, then they are slower still. Don't get hung up on ping being the issue. It's far more likely to be just a symptom, not the cause.

Comment: Turn off the VM, and then you can change settings.  Try 1 CPU, 4 cores and 8GB of RAM instead.  VMware Workstation/Player doesn't use your video hardware (and doesn't offer any video hardware passthrough) so graphics will be slow as it's all emulated by the host CPU.